# How to convert a word in string to binary

Tags: python, string, binary, hex

I was working on a module(the `import module` stuff) which would help to convert words in string to `hex` and `binary`(And octal if possible).I finished the hex part.But now I am struggling in case of the binary.I don't know where to start from or what to do.What I want to do is simple.It would take an input string such as `'test'`.The function inside the module would convert it to binary.

What I have done till now is given below:

```
def string_hex(string): # Converts a word to hex
    keyword = string.encode()
    import binascii
    hexadecimal=str(binascii.hexlify(keyword), 'ascii')
    formatted_hex=':'.join(hexadecimal[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(hexadecimal), 2))
    return formatted_hex

def hex_string(hexa):
# hexa(Given this name because there is a built-in function hex()) should be written as string.For accuracy on words avoid symbols(, . !)
    string = bytes.fromhex(hexa)
    formatted_string = string.decode()
    return formatted_string
```

I saved in the directory where I have installed my python in the name `experiment.py`.This is the way I call it.

```
>>> from experiment import string_hex
>>> string_hex('test')
'74:65:73:74'
```

Just like that I am able to convert it back also like this:

```
>>> from experiment import hex_string
>>> hex_string('74657374')
'test'
```

Just like this wanted to convert words in strings to binary.And one more thing I am using `python 3.4.2`.Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows. You don't even have to import `binascii`.

```
def string_hex(string):
    return ':'.join(format(ord(c), 'x') for c in string)

def hex_string(hexa):
    hexgen = (hexa[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(hexa), 2))
    return ''.join(chr(eval('0x'+n)) for n in hexgen)

def string_bin(string):
    return ':'.join(format(ord(c), 'b') for c in string)

def bin_string(binary):
    bingen = (binary[i:i+7] for i in range(0, len(binary), 7))
    return ''.join(chr(eval('0b'+n)) for n in bingen)
```

And here is the output:

```
>>> string_hex('test')
'74:65:73:74'
>>> hex_string('74657374')
'test'
>>> string_bin('test')
'1110100:1100101:1110011:1110100'
>>> bin_string('1110100110010111100111110100')
'test'
```